# How do I insert rows from another table and update at the same time?

Tags: sql, oracle

Table A:

```
A|B|C|Version

1|2|3|1

1|2|3|2
```

I want table B to be

```
A|B|C|Version

1|2|3|2
```

Every row is the same as A except Version is increased by 1.
Let's say I only want to copy the rows from table A where version=1. 
How do I do that?

Comment: Do you have a PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 0):

[insert into](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert-select.html) for "copying" + [Where clause](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj33602.html) for only getting the one version "copied".

```
INSERT INTO tableB ( A, B, C, Version) VALUES
    (SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE tableA.Version = 1);
```

Comment: I already knew that one. But what if I wanted to increase version by 1 in that set of values?

Comment: if you wouldn't mind setting up a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) I can get you an answer pretty quick.

Comment: I'm having trouble setting up sqlfiddle... Nvm then

Comment: If you're going to do an `INSERT ... SELECT`, you would omit the `VALUES` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO b( a, b, c, version )
  SELECT a, b, c, version + 1
    FROM a
   WHERE version = 1
```

would work.  Of course, since your `WHERE` clause limits you to just the rows where `version = 1`, you could just use a hard-coded 2 in your `SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO b( a, b, c, version )
  SELECT a, b, c, 2
    FROM a
   WHERE version = 1
```